# Video for Linux (V4L) generator driver

Tags: linux, video, v4l2

I would like to experiment with tvheadend but prior to investing in an actual capture card I was wondering if V4L supports a "generate" capture "card" that can just offer video stream of an image or pre-selected video file from the V4L device; a test pattern if you will. That way I can see if all the bits and pieces will work prior to investing an actual TV tuner card/USB device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Virtual Video Driver (VIVI) or the V4L Test Suite.

These create dummy devices that you can  use to test your system.

Details are on the [V4L page](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/V4L_Test_Suite).

Comment: Great info, I also found some other "loop back" projects such as [this one](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) but I'll start with the official test suite.